# Error when stopping services IIs with windows powershell

Tags: powershell

I created a function in powershell that has the purpose of restarting 3 specific services of the IIs. When I call it, I get an error, the detail is that it's only on stopping the service, I can list it, I just can't restart or stop it. I'm as admin.

function Restart_webAppPool(){

```
$ArrayIIS = @(Get-IISAppPool -Name NAME1, NAME2, NAME3)

Import-Module WebAdministration 

foreach($process in $ArrayIIS ){

Stop-WebAppPool $process.Name

}
```

}

return:
Exception calling "Stop" with "0" argument(s): "The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
0x8007007E)"
At C:\script\script.ps1:104 char:1

- (Get-IISAppPool("NaME1")).stop()
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this directly as I don't have an IIS instance at hand, but potentially the process name isn't being parsed as a string?

Does it work if you specifically convert it to a string?

```
$ArrayIIS = @(Get-IISAppPool -Name NAME1, NAME2, NAME3)

Import-Module WebAdministration 

foreach($process in $ArrayIIS ){

$name = $process.Name.ToString()

Stop-WebAppPool $name

}
```